# Vielbeins for Euclidean BTZ metric

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor

Need help in finding vielbeins for Euclidean BTZ metric,
$$ds^2 = \left(f + \frac{j^2}{4r^2}\right) dt^2 + \frac{1}{f}dr^2 + r^2d\phi^2 - jdtd\phi$$

The problem is, I verified that this metric cannot be diagonalized by any orthogonal transformation and from the source I am learning about vielbeins, they are defined only when we have a orthogonal transformation diagonalizing the metric in a way

\begin{align}
&g_{\mu\nu} = O^a_{\hskip0.4em\mu} D_{ab}O^b_{\hskip0.4em\nu}
\\\\
&O^a_{\hskip0.4em\mu} = (O^{-1})_\mu^{\hskip0.4em a}
\end{align}

Then we can define $e^a_\mu = \sqrt{\lambda^a}O^a_{\hskip0.4em\mu}$ and write $g_{\mu\nu} = e^a_\mu \eta_{ab}e^b_\nu$.

Comment: You can try $e^0 = \sqrt{f}dt$, $e^1=\frac{j}{2r}dt -rd\phi$ and $e^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}dr$, they will provide the metric given.

Comment: Oh!..  Isn't this giving a "-j/2" with cross term instead of "-j"

Comment: you can compute the square of $e^1$ with the binomial formula, which provides you with a term $-2ab$, the $2$ cancels out the $2$ in the denominator.